# How to avoid StreamWriter from writing partial data to file

Tags: c#, .net, file, serialization, streamwriter

I'm using a *StreamWriter* to write data to a file. The data is a (potentially) long string that should be saved in full.

I've seen cases where the file is created, but its contents are not the entire string; that is - the string appears to have been "cut" during saving, and not saved in its entirety.

The "buggy" file i have contains exactly 4096 characters, which is exactly the length of the internal buffer used by the StreamWriter class.

Example, similar to the code we're using:

```
string output = "......" // long string

sw = File.CreateText(filename);

if (fileWriter == null)
{ 
    return;
}

try
{
    sw.Write (output);
}
finally
{
    if (sw != null)
    {
        sw.Close ();
    }
}
```

**My question is**:

is this an expected scenario?
e.g: can *StreamWriter* write only part of the string it should save? if so, is there any simple way to overcome this ?

Comment: can I confirm: you're only making one call to `Write`, and that value is a single `string`? if so: perhaps prefer `File.WriteAllText(filename, output)` ?

Comment: Try calling the [Flush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.flush?view=netframework-4.8) method on it and see if it still happens

Comment: @MindSwipe I wouldn't *expect* that to change things, because `Close` calls `Dispose(true)`, and `Dispose(true)` calls `Flush`; I guess anything is possible, though! (especially if different versions .of .NET are involved)

Comment: @MarcGravell I meant to periodically call it, so loop over the string 4096 characters at a time and write it buffer by buffer. And instead of calling Flush manually, OP could also set `AutoFlush` to true

Comment: also note: if the process was forcibly killed during write, or the computer lost power etc: yes, it is entirely possible to have a partially written file; if you need to avoid that edge scenario, a common approach is to write the file to a temporary name, and then *rename* the files when they are fully written

Comment: @MindSwipe it *already* flushes periodically, though (when the internal buffer is full); setting `AutoFlush` just makes it flush after every write operation; I'm not saying that can't be useful - I'm just saying that *in this scenario*, it kinda shouldn't make a difference, really; `AutoFlush` and manual `Flush()` calls are more useful when dealing with things like network sockets, where you want to make sure that a frame *actually gets sent across the network*, rather than sitting waiting for more data that will never come; it isn't really very helpful *in this scenario*

Comment: @MarcGravell yes, only a single call to Write with a single string.
Regarding the "rename" technique - isn't it also possible to forcibly kill the app during rename? won't it suffer from the same problem?

Comment: @lysergic-acid that's the OS-es problem, and the OS is pretty good at avoiding that problem, with robust file-system mechanisms specifically for that

Comment: @MarcGravell also, i just checked now, and File.WriteAllText internally just uses a StreamWriter, so i think it's a no go... 
so can anyone post an answer that is not a comment ?